# Woocommerce - Get variable in woocommerce_before_save_order_items

Tags: php, post, woocommerce

I am trying to make select box to change tax class at admin datail order in Woo. I made column, select box with tax classes, but i cannot save it.

My code in functions.php is like that

```
function tax_edit_col_h($order){
  ?>
  <th class="line_changetax">
    Change TAX
  </th>
  <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'tax_edit_col_h' );

function tax_change($item) {
  ?>
  <td class="line_changetax">
      <select name="change_tax" id="change_tax_select" style="width:100%;">
  <?php
        $arraytax = WC_Tax::get_tax_class_slugs();
            echo '<option value="'.$item->get_tax_class().'">'.$item->get_tax_class().'</option>';
        foreach($arraytax as $tax){
            echo '<option value="'.$tax.'">'.$tax.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
      </select>
  </td>
  <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'tax_change' );

function change_tax_save(){
    echo var_dump($_POST['change_tax']);
    WC_Order_Item_Product::set_tax_class($_POST['change_tax']); 
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_save_order_items', 'change_tax_save', 10, 2 );
```

dump of "Change_tax" is NULL

[image: Here is screenshot of admin]

Many thanks for help guys...

Comment: On woocommerce admin, order items are only editable on specific order statuses like "on-hold"… The data is managed through Ajax and handled by WC_Ajax Class… So you can't add a dropdown in a simple way (as you do) to update specific order item properties… This is much more complicated than your approach.

Comment: Now it runs almost perfectly, here is code 
`
function change_order_item_tax_class( $item ) {
    if ( 'line_item' === $item->get_type() && isset($_POST['change_tax']) ) {
   $item->set_tax_class($_POST['change_tax']);
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_save_order_item', 'change_order_item_tax_class' ); 
`
But there is still one problem - it changes by the last item (more at video below)
[here is video](https://streamable.com/02ceea)